# What is the relation between parsing languages and checking languages?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, parsers

I have looked at a number of textbooks on computability theory. They typically have the following form:

- Define a language class (regular, context-free, context-sensitive, recursively enumerable)
- Define an automaton that **recognizes** the class (finite automaton, pushdown automaton, linear-bounded automaton, turing machine)

However, another fundamental question is how to **parse** a language. I have not found an treatment of parsing as a computational problem in these textbooks.

**Is there a simple relation between an automaton that recognizes a language, and an automaton that parses the language (and outputs a parse tree)?**

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple relation between the two problems, but it goes in only one side: if you can parse, then you can recognize. Indeed, if you run the parser and it outputs failure, then the input is not in the language; if the parser produces a parse tree, the input is in the language.

Note, however, that a parser and a recognizer are not only solving different problems, but are also given different specs. A recognizer is given a language in some abstract form. In contrast, a parser is given a grammar, which not only implicitly defines a language, but also instructs the parser how to convert a valid input into a parse tree. Since the same language can have many equivalent grammars, it's not clear what it even means to convert a recognizer to a parser – what grammar should the parser use?

Why are recognizers interesting, then? Precisely because of the one-sided connection, which states that a parser can be converted to a recognizer. This relation implies that if your language is hard to recognize, then you won't be able to parse it (using a certain class of algorithms).

Comment: *"Why are recognizers interesting, then? Precisely because of the one-sided connection, which states that a parser can be converted to a recognizer. This relation implies that if your language is hard to recognize, then you won't be able to parse it (using a certain class of algorithms)."* this is clarifying. Thanks.

Comment: Cntd. But it doesnt answer the other direction: given a grammar that generates a type n language, we can construct a type n automaton that recognizes it, but can we also construct a type n automaton that parses it? Or is it sometimes the case that you need for example a turing machine to parse a context free grammar even though you can have a pushdown automaton to recognize it?

Comment: As I explained in my answer, given just a language, you cannot possibly parse it, since parsing requires a grammar. The Chomsky hierarchy is a hierarchy of recognizers, not a hierarchy of parsers. A "type $n$ automaton" is a recognizer. It cannot possibly parse anything.

Comment: Yes I understand that you need a grammar to parse a string as you explained in the answer. But parsing is ALSO a task to be performed, and at least a Turing machine can do this for arbitrary grammars. I am asking: if we know that the language of a grammar G is recognizable by e.g. a pushdown automaton (so we know G is a context-free grammar), does that also tell us something about the automaton that we need to parse G? e.g. could we construct a pushdown automaton (a different one from the one used to recognize L(G) ) to parse G?

Comment: Same language can have many equivalent grammars —> and the same grammar and input can have many parse trees!

Comment: There are several different algorithms for parsing context-free grammars. Some of them (like CYK) work for all context-free grammars, some of them (LR) only for a subset of these grammars, but much faster. CYK is not built on top of a PDA, whereas LR does use a stack.

Comment: @user56834: in the common case where the semantics of the parse are expressed using BNF augmented with attribute assignment, the final parse tree can be recovered from the list of derivations applied. Different derivation orders will lead to different attribute calculation orders but provided the attribute assignments are functional, the end result will be the same. In that sense, there is a strong relationship between parsing and recognising with a particular grammar, as well as providing a natural definition for strong and weak grammar equivalence.

Comment: Just an example: We have a grammar S->P, S->N, P->{ 1^n: n is prime }, N-> { 1^n: n is composite }. Any sequence of 1's is obviously in the language, so it is very easy to recognise. Put to find the first step in the parse tree, we need to determine if n is prime or not which isn't _very_ difficult, but also not very easy for large n, and I'm sure someone can come up with worse examples.